# Form date format in php

Tags: php

I have a month from 1 to 12. How can I form a date in `Y-m-d` format with the current year?

Example:

I have the month 6.
Output should be `2016-06-01`

And also how to get the next month of a specified date?

Example:

```
2016-07-01 ----- 2016-08-01

2016-12-01 ----- 2017-01-01
```

Comment: Simple date format goes thus date("Y-m-d"). You can read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I guess you can find the answer for your first part of your Q here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_create.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setDate](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php) of **DateTime**. First create DateTime object and **setDate()** with current year, `specified month`(1 to 12) and `1` as date.

Like this,

```
<?php

$date=new DateTime();
$date->setDate($date->format('Y'), 6, 1);  // change 6 with the month digit you have.

echo $date->format("Y-m-d");

$date->modify("+1 month");
echo "\n";

echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

**Output:**

```
2016-06-01
2016-07-01
```

To add a month in date you can use [modify()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) function to add a month in DateTime object.

Demo: https://eval.in/636688

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `mktime` function in combination with `date` function

```
$month=6;
echo date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, date('d'), date('Y')));
/* 2016-06-07 */

$month++;
echo date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, date('d'), date('Y')));
/* 2016-07-07 */
```

Comment: $month++ will increment month only. What if month is in December and year also get increment if it is December. Example: 2016-12-01 and your output is 2016-13-01 but i need is 2017-01-01

Answer (score 0):

To get the current year

```
date('Y');
```

More on formating here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

This will give you +1 month from the date you provide

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime('2016-12-01')));
```